# Trouble with keyboard using FBConnect iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, keyboard, facebook

I'm having a persistent though intermittent issue using the Facebook Connect SDK with the iPhone. The login works fine, but when I'm on an FBDialog to make a post the keyboard input will fail to go to the Textfield on the Dialog. You have to dismiss the keyboard and tap the field (sometimes 3 or 4 times) before the input will go to the text field. 
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with an old version of the FB Connect SDK. It seemed to work just as well, but it didn't exhibit the same problem with the keyboard. Not an ideal solution, but it works for now.